# Sqlite query execution takes more time on Mac

Tags: c++, c, macos, sqlite

I have a table with around 2,00,000 entries. Trying to insert or update a row takes more time in Mac than it does on windows. 
It is the same with Select query as well. I m using sqlite 3 (version 3.7.5 )
What could be the issue?

Update : I could reduce the time to 8.5 min by using various pragma options

```
PRAGMA synchronous = OFF
PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF
PRAGMA cache_size = 20000
PRAGMA page_size = 4000
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY
PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE
```

I tried using memory mapped io too. But its not helping . Any help on this?
PRAGMA mmap_size = 500000
As mentioned in the comments, I m using a MAC (Mac - mini). HDD, 4GB Ram.

Another Update  : I found out while debugging that sqlite3_step takes some time. not every sqlite_step but its random sqlite3_step. Since I could not step into this function I could not debug any thing more. Is there any idea what may be the issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: How much more time? Are the machines identical otherwise?

Comment: It takes about 2 min for a couple of automated queries. The same queries takes about 25 min in Mac. No, the machines are not identical. The Mac has 4 GB internal storage. PC has 16 GB. Vacuum does solve the problem, but vacuum by itself takes about 10 min. All this happens faster in PC

Comment: Am I missing some compilation options for mac?

Comment: Is the data on the local disk in both cases? Or is it network mounted? Are you using HFS+?

Comment: Yes, the data is on the local disk. And it is HFS+

Comment: Rotating disks, or SSD?

Comment: It might be possible to optimize the queries (on both systems). Show the database schema, and the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output for the slow query.

Comment: It is HDD, does that matter? 
And what is intriguing is that the same query take different time both on MAC and PC. I would not bother if it was taking almost the same time. But the difference is huge. Through any tool like Sqlite Studio it is takes different time when compared to the time it take via code. So that is why I wanted to know if I m doing some thing wrong while compiling the sqlite in MAC.

Comment: This is the result of Query plan for one query : 
SEARCH TABLE Product_Common_Information USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Product_Common_Information_1 (prodId=?)

Query is : Explain query plan Update Product_Common_Information  Set oldName = "233_HD_Lowerthird1" where prodId = "80722"

There are around 1,00,000 queries of this sort.

Comment: What is this weird "1,00,000" notation?

Comment: Is it the same version of SQLite on both platforms?  A recent post on the SQLite mailing list saw a large slow-down when using an old version (and even if they _are_ the same, 3.7.5 is quite old, so updating may be worthwhile).

Comment: I will try that and check